# Applying De Morgan's Laws

Tags: logic

I have recently started working on De Morgan's laws and Boolean algebra at school, and i just cant seem to get my head around it. We were given a worksheet to complete, here are some of the questions:

1) Using De Morgan's Laws, simplify the following: Not(A AND B) OR A

2) Using De Morgan's Laws, show that A + A.B = A

I've done some research my self and have tried to understand it, but i just cant, I do understand the terms such as and,or not etc. but i don't understand how De Morgan's laws work or how to apply them.

Sorry if the title is wrong or misleading to what im asking, i don't use this site much and thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Not(A AND B) is equivalent to (Not A) OR (Not B).

Comment: Suggestion: try to use symbols in a consistent manner: why $+, .$ and also AND, OR, ?

Comment: I know what the laws are, i just don't understand how to apply them, and i was using differentiating symbols/terms to show what they could be.

Comment: see for example [how-to-apply-de-morgans-law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416040/how-to-apply-de-morgans-law)

Comment: Ill take a look at this, thanks for the input !

Comment: ... not sure what DeMorgan has to do with problem 2) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) Using De Morgan's Laws, simplify the following: Not(A AND B) OR A
```

The trick for this one is as follow:

```
    NOT(A AND B) OR A
<=> NOT(A) OR NOT(B) OR A      // The trick is here. Literally De Morgan's law.
<=> (NOT(A) OR A) OR NOT(B)
<=> TRUE OR NOT(B)
<=> TRUE
```

So this `(1)` is a tautology.

```
2) Using De Morgan's Laws, show that A + A.B = A
```

And for this one, here is the trick:

```
    A + A.B
<=> A OR (A AND B)       
<=> A AND (TRUE OR B)    // The trick is here. like in Math:  x + (x*y) = x*(1+y)
<=> A AND TRUE
<=> A
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Much appreciated, this helped alot as i can now see how/where the laws are applied, ill practice some more and see how i get on.